# Can we construct a nonzero function $f(x)$ near (but not at a point) such that the integral evaluates to $1$?

Tags: epsilon-delta, dirac-delta

I want to construct a function that is nonzero between $[-t,0) \cup  (0,t]$, as $t \to 0$, such that the limit of the integral across $[-t,0) \cup (0,t]$ equals $1$. The function can be scaled in amplitude by $t$.

Also outside of $t$, the function must equals zero.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're asking for (is the domain $[-t,0)\cup (0,t]$? Or the desired image?) but most likely this is what you're looking for: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function

Comment: [-t,0)U(0,t] is the domain (understanding that we will let t approach 0) and the function, over those two intervals is nonzero. Additionally, the integral of the function is 1.

Comment: Informally, the function will be "squeezed" (like a rectangular function in the derivation for Dirac delta function) but unlike the rectangular function, there is a discontinuity at t=0